# Clever ways of "summarising" the equity fund universe

Tags: equities

I am trying to get some advice or direction (brainstorm) as to the best way to summarise/cluster/etc. the equity fund universe (which for my purposes consists of about 150 funds).

Some of my ideas at current:

-I have access to a Value and Growth Index so could perhaps try segregate funds into value/momentum/growth groups by looking at their betas to these indices. Could also do the same to estimate the funds' exposures to certain sectors: Large Cap, Mid Cap, Small Cap; Resources, Financials, Industrials; etc.

-regression on index to see which funds are closet benchmark trackers (or look at tracking error)

-maybe PCA on the equity fund universe to see which funds are more dissimilar to universe...

I am really just looking for several ways of analysing the funds and try to get some groupings or measures of similarity between the funds. Any pointers of what to read up on or suggestions would be appreciated

PS: I would be using R for this work so if there are any R-specific libraries to look at then please notify

Comment: perhaps look into k-means clustering?

Comment: The "BEST" way will strongly depend on what you want to achieve by this. You can analyse funds by cost, by past performance by active share by fund management company and so on and so on. So what are your goals when clustering?

Answer (score 1):

Capital IQ has an existing classifications by asset class, country, family, method, region, sector, size, and style. These definitely are not clever classifications, but form the baseline for fund taxonomy.

- AssetClass

  > ```
  > Alternative   ALTERN
  > Commodities   COMMOD
  > Currencies    CURR
  > Equity    EQUITY
  > Fixed Income  FIXINC
  > Mixed Assets  MIXASST
  > ```
- country follows ISO standards
- Family

  > ```
  > BLDRS BLDRS
  > Claymore  CLAYMORE
  > Currency Shares (Rydex)   CURRENCY
  > Direxion  DIREXION
  > Exchange Traded Notes ETNS
  > First Trust   FTRUST
  > FocusShares   FOCUS
  > HealthShares  HEALTHSH
  > HOLDRS    HOLDRS
  > iShares   ISHARES
  > Macro Shares  MACROSH
  > Market Vectors    MVECTORS
  > Miscellaneous MISCL
  > NETS (Northern Trust) NETS
  > PowerShares   POWERSH
  > ProShares PROSH
  > Realty Funds  REALTY
  > RevenueShares REVSH
  > Rydex RYDEX
  > SPA   SPA
  > SPDR  SPDR
  > TDX Independence  TDX
  > United States Trust   USTRUST
  > Vanguard  VANGUARD
  > Wisdom Tree   WISDOM
  > ```
- Method

> ```
> Hedged    HEDGED
> Leveraged Long    LEVLONG
> Leveraged Short   LEVSHORT
> Quant Model   QUANT
> Special Weights   SPWEIGHTS
> Standard Long STANLONG
> Standard Short    STANSHORT
> ```

- Region

> ```
> Asia  ASIA
> BRIC-Chindia  BRIC
> Developed DEVELOP
> Emerging  EMERG
> Europe    EUROPE
> Global    GLOBAL
> Global Ex US  GLOBALXUS
> Latin America LATIN
> MidEast-Africa    MIDEAST
> North America NAMERICA
> Pacific Ex Japan  PACIFIC
> ```

- Sector

> ```
> Agriculture   AGRIC
> Alternate Energy  ALTENERGY
> Consumer  CONSUMER
> Energy    ENERGY
> Financial FINANCIAL
> General   GENSECT
> Healthcare    HEALTHCAR
> Housing   HOUSING
> Industrials   INDUST
> Infrastructure    INFRASTR
> Materials MATERIALS
> Municipal fixed inc   MUNIS
> Precious Metals   PRECIOUS
> Real Estate   REALEST
> Resources (General)   RESOURC
> Services  SERVICES
> Social    SOCIAL
> Special Theme SPECIAL
> Taxable Fixed Inc TXFIXINC
> Technology    TECHNOL
> Telecomm  TELECOMM
> Timber    TIMBER
> Transportation    TRANSPORT
> Utilities UTILITIES
> Water WATER
> ```

- Size

> ```
> General   GENSIZE
> Large-Mega    ETF_LARGECAP
> Mid   ETF_MIDCAP
> Small-Micro   ETF_SMALLCAP
> ```

- Style

> ```
> Equity Income EQINCOME
> General   GENSTYLE
> General Fixed Inc GENFIXINC
> Growth    GROWTH
> High Yield Fixed Inc  HIGHYLD
> Intermediate Fixed Inc    INTFIXINC
> Long Fixed Inc    LTFIXINC
> Short Fixed Inc   STFIXINC
> Value VALUE
> ```

Answer (score 0):

for model construction purposes, I would suggest factor analysis or PCA.  Have a look at [EM algorithm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/EMCluster/EMCluster.pdf)

Comment: The EM algorithm is rather general. You mean EM-clustering. Would usual clustering (k-means, hyrarchical) do the same? Which distance measure would you propose?